# How large of a SQL string (for mass update) can I realistically use in C# .net4?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, sql-update

I'm recieving and parsing a large text file.

In that file I have a numerical ID identifying a row in a table, and another field that I need to update.

```
ID       Current Location
=========================
1        Boston
2        Cambridge
3        Idaho
```

I was thinking of creating a single SQL command string and firing that off using ADO.Net, but some of these files I'm going to recieve have thousands of lines. Is this doable or is there a limit I'm not seeing?

Comment: `I think your first question would be how are you going to parse / split that file so that it can be readable in regards to capturing the `ID and the contents that you need to update, then from there you would need to think about your `Iteration` process and how you are going to update the database, you could store this information in a `List<T>`, updates could also be done using `Dictionary<int,string>` etc...

Comment: Have you considered parsing your file into XML?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: For the purpose of this question assume I've already done that (I have). I'm just asking **specifically** about the performance hit of iterating through CollectionX and building a string using `StringBuilder` and **pushing that through to MSSQL**.

Comment: Performance issues aside, building a SQL statement with the StringBuilder is just begging for SQL Injection.

Comment: @Serg - Can you narrow down some the facts? If you have an XML document that is the source of the data, then can you update your example, so its an XML document? The size of your query would realy depend on the performance capabilities of the server.

Comment: @Ramhound: My data source is an Excel file similar to what I posted above in the table section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you may have thousands of lines, then composing a SQL statement is definitely *NOT* the way to go.  Better code-based alternatives include:

1. Use SQLBulkCopy to insert the change data to a staging table and then UPDATE your target table using the staging table as the source.  It also has excellent [batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx) options (unlike the other choices)
2. Write a stored procedure to do the Update that accepts an XML parameter that contains the UPDATE data.
3. Write a stored procedure to do the Update that accepts a table-valued parameter that contains the UPDATE data.

I have not compared them myself but it is my understanding that #3 is generally the fastest (though #1 is plenty fast for almost any need).

Answer (score 1):

Writing one huge INSERT statement well be very slow. You also don't want to parse the whole massive file at once. What you need to do is something along the lines of:

1. Figure out a good chunk size. Let's call it `chunk_size`. This will be the number of records you'll read from the file at a time.
2. Load `chunk_size` number of records from the file into a DataTable.
3. Use [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to insert the DataTable into the DB.
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until the file is done.

You'll have to experiment to find an optimal size for `chunk_size` so start small and work your way up.

Comment: This is unnecessary with SQLBulkCopy, which has its own batching capabilities built-in.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - But a DataTable is an in-memory construct. If you load the whole file into a DataTable you may run out of memory.

Comment: SQLBulkCopy is also streaming, there is no need to load the whole file into memory at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of an actual limit, if one exists, but why not take "bite sized" chunks of the file that you feel comfortable with and break it into several commands?  You can always wrap it in a single transaction if it's important that they all fail or succeed.

Say grab 250 lines at a time, or whatever.